# Using Swapfile for Hibernation with BTRFS and Kernel 5.0.16-gentoo

Tags: linux-kernel, hibernate

I created a swap file as described here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Swap#Swap_file_creation

When I try to hibernate I get the following error:

```bsh
$ echo disk > /sys/power/state
echo: write error: no such device
```

Also in dmesg, I get:

```bsh
[30721.352822] [drm] Reducing the compressed framebuffer size. This may lead to less power savings than a non-reduced-size. Try to increase stolen memory size if available in BIOS.
[30721.454735] acpi LNXPOWER:07: Turning OFF
[30721.454987] acpi LNXPOWER:02: Turning OFF
[30721.455365] acpi LNXPOWER:01: Turning OFF
[30721.455563] PM: Cannot find swap device, try swapon -a
[30721.455563] PM: Cannot get swap writer
[30721.553943] OOM killer enabled.
[30721.553944] Restarting tasks ... done.
```

As described in https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate#Hibernation_into_swap_file, I set the following kernel params:

```
resume=UUID=2bfb4ccd-6b80-4806-8a08-4f1e67ef035f
resume_offset=148378880
```

Here is how I get the resume_offset and resume parameter values:

```
$ filefrag -v /swapfile
Filesystem type is: 9123683e
File size of /swapfile is 536870912 (131072 blocks of 4096 bytes)
 ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
   0:        0..       0:  148378880.. 148378880:      1:            
   1:        1..  131071:  148378881.. 148509951: 131071:             last,unwritten,eof
```

```
$ findmnt -no SOURCE,UUID -T /swapfile
/dev/mapper/nvme0n1p2[/root] 2bfb4ccd-6b80-4806-8a08-4f1e67ef035f
```

When I try to use `swap_offset`, I get the following issue:

```
$ swap-offset /swapfile 
ioctl(FIBMAP) failed: Invalid argument
```

So is it even possible to use a swapfile for hibernation when using BTRFS? It seems that the kernel is not aware of the correction location of the swap file.

Comment: https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#Does_btrfs_support_swap_files.3F

Comment: The wiki page says that since kernel 5, swapfile is supported. I'm using kernel 5.0.16. Did I miss s.th. in this article?

Comment: "Swap file - must be fully allocated as NOCOW with no compression on one device.": What does they mean with "on one device"?

Comment: NOCOW and compression should be disabled as I created the swapfile as described here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Swap#Swap_file_creation

Comment: I've found this: https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/aydzo4/btrfs_with_swapfile_cannot_find_swap_device/

Comment: @dmorlock Btrfs supports spreading a single partition across several devices, usually for use with RAID.

Answer (score 4):

u/hjoke (https://www.reddit.com/user/kjoke/) made my day:

filefrag calculates the offset incorrectly for BTRFS but there is a script that calculate the correct offset: https://github.com/osandov/osandov-linux/blob/master/scripts/btrfs_map_physical.c

Download and `gcc btrfs_map_physical.c -o btrfs_map_physical` then get the first physical offset for the swap file:

```
$ sudo ./btrfs-map-physical /swap | head -n2
FILE OFFSET EXTENT TYPE LOGICAL SIZE    LOGICAL OFFSET  PHYSICAL SIZE   DEVID   PHYSICAL OFFSET
0   regular 4096    607759892480    268435456   1   608833634304
```

Here: `608833634304`. Divide this offset by the page size:

```
$ getconf PAGESIZE
4096
```

So the `resume_offset` is `608833634304 / 4096 = 148641024`. Add this value with the `resume` parameter as kernel params and reboot. Afterwards `systemd hibernate` will still fail because systemd ignores kernel params and calculate the offset incorrectly but `echo disk > /sys/power/state` works.