# Hibernation with swap file under BTRFS

Tags: swap, hibernate

I am trying to get hibernation to work in Arch Linux. I am using a swap file in BTRFS, which is under a separate subvolume from `/` (both are under subvolume ID 5 A.K.A top-level). I am also using disk encryption with dm-crypt.

I have:

- Added the `resume` hook after `keyboard` but before `fsck`.
- Added the resume kernel parameter as follows: `resume=UUID=*UUID of mapped LUKS device*`
- Added the resume offset as follows: `resume_offset=*offset*`

I have tried the following methods to get the resume offset:

- Filefrag: `filefrag -v *swap path* | awk '{ if($1=="0:"){print $4} }'`, from the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/1index.php/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate#About_swap_partition/file_size)
- A script: [btrfs_map_physical.c](https://github.com/osandov/osandov-linux/blob/master/scripts/btrfs_map_physical.c), from [this StackExchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/521686/using-swapfile-for-hibernation-with-btrfs-and-kernel-5-0-16-gentoo) (I also tried the other hibernation method instead of systemd)

When I execute `systemctl hibernate` the monitor turns off but then immediately turns back on. Since I am not using the `quiet` kernel parameter, this message is printed in the TTY:

```
[7695.071873] tpm tpm0: tpm_try_transmit: send(): error -5
[7695.770207] PM: Cannot find swap device, try swapon -a
[7695.770223] PM: Cannot get swap writer
```

Similar messages come when using the alternate method.